# PowerBI end of month

Tags: date, time, powerbi, percentage

I'm using monthly data and trying to display YoY% calculations.

However, my code is not robust for different end-of-month dates caused by leap years, I think.

```
Value YoY% 2 = 

VAR START_DATE = DATEADD('DATA'[Date], -12, MONTH) 

RETURN

   DIVIDE(SUM(DATA[Value]), CALCULATE(SUM(DATA[Value]),START_DATE))-1
```

[image: the negative spikes are in feb]

I'm very much a power BI novice. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Value YoY% 2 = 
VAR Curr_Year = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(DATA[Date]))
VAR Last_Year = Curr_Year - 1 
RETURN
   DIVIDE(
      CALCULATE(SUM(DATA[Value]), FILTER(DATA, YEAR(DATA[Date]) = Curr_Year)),
      CALCULATE(SUM(DATA[Value]), FILTER(DATA, YEAR(DATA[Date]) = Last_Year))
   )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the code isn't working: returns no values.

Comment: Oh, in that case, please share sample data or report.